# How to uninstall python apps?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I am following [this tutorial](http://ingeniapp.com/en/using-2-2-lcd-spi-in-python-with-raspberry-pi/). One of the steps is:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

How to uninstall that setup.py apps?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all files manually, and also undo any other stuff that installation did manually.

If you don't know the list of all files, you can reinstall it with the `--record` option, and take a look at the list this produces.

To record list of installed files, you can use:

`python setup.py install --record files.txt`

Once you want to uninstall you can use xargs to do the removal:

`cat files.txt | xargs rm -rf`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall)

Comment: hi..thanks. unfortunately, the pi just shows blank even before I had a change to try your solution. I reboot but nothing showed up. I just did reimage the micro SD card.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need super user permissions to remove them.

hence

```
python setup.py install --record files.txt
```

use `xargs` to remove the content with sudo permission

```
cat files.txt | sudo xargs rm -rf
```

Since you have installed it using `sudo python setup.py install` you need the correct permissions to remove it from the system too.